# The space of all Borel probability measures is connected w.r.t. the topology induced by weak convergence

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, connectedness, weak-convergence, borel-measures

Let $E$ be a topological space and $\mathcal P (E)$ the space of all Borel probability measures on $E$. We endow $\mathcal P (E)$ with the topology of [weak convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures). Could you have a check on my attempt of below theorem?

> **Theorem:** $\mathcal P (E)$ is connected.

---

**Proof:** Fix $\mu, \nu \in \mathcal P (E)$ and Consider the map
$$
\varphi: [0, 1] \to \mathcal P(E), t \mapsto t \mu + (1-t) \nu.
$$

Then $\varphi (1) = \mu$ and $\varphi (0) = \nu$. Let's prove that $\varphi$ is continuous. Let $(t_n) \subset [0, 1]$ such that $t_n \to t \in [0, 1]$. Let $f:E \to \mathbb R$ be bounded continuous. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\int f \mathrm d [t_n \mu + (1-t_n) \nu] &= t_n \int f \mathrm d \mu + (1-t_n) \int f \mathrm d \nu \\
&\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} t \int f \mathrm d \mu + (1-t) \int f \mathrm d \nu \\
&= \int f \mathrm d [t \mu + (1-t) \nu].
\end{align}
$$

Hence $t_n \mu + (1-t_n) \nu \rightharpoonup t \mu + (1-t) \nu$. It follows that $\mathcal P (E)$ is path-connected and thus connected.

Comment: It seems to be correct! You can also check this (similar) post, where Giuseppe Negro's answer remarks on the essential aspects of the proof (the space of Borel probability measures is a convex subset of the topological vector space of signed Borel measures in which addition and multiplication by a scalar are continuous):
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2639951/is-the-space-of-borel-probability-measures-over-r-connected?rq=1